# Wait for variable change in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, onitemclicklistener

I have thumbnails `Gallery picGallery`, where the pictures are asynchronously downloaded. Then I have `ImageView picView` where should be placed the bigger image when clicked on thumbnail. Problem is that when I click on thumbnail before the thumbnail is downloaded - the BitmapDrawable is null.

```
picGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)((ImageView)v).getDrawable();
            picView.setImageBitmap(bd.getBitmap());

        }
    });
```

I'd like to put some preloader to picView while `BitmapDrawable bd` is null, so I need to wait for the variable change somehow. How to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to put some preloader to picView while BitmapDrawable bd is
>   null, so I need to wait for the variable change somehow. How to make
>   it?

In the `OnItemClickListener` check to see if the `Bitmap` isn't `null`. If it isn't `null` then set it as the background. If it's `null` then set the `picView` with a default image(like *Loading...*) so the user sees something right away and set a `boolean` flag `requireUpdate`. In the `AsyncTask` or whatever asynchronously method you have for loading the images, when the image is fully loaded, check that `requireUpdate` flag. If the flag is true also set the `Bitmap` directly to `picView`(you may need to also store the position of the clicked thumbnail to know the image you're targeting).